# Is there a less painful way to GetBytes for a buffer not starting at 0?

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter

I am having to deal with raw bytes in a project and I need to basically do something like this

```
byte[] ToBytes(){
  byte[] buffer=new byte[somelength];
  byte[] tmp;
  tmp=BitConverter.GetBytes(SomeShort);
  buffer[0]=tmp[0];
  buffer[1]=tmp[1];
  tmp=BitConverter.GetBytes(SomeOtherShort);
  buffer[2]=tmp[0];
  buffer[3]=tmp[1];
}
```

I feel like this is so wrong yet I can't find any better way of doing it. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BinaryWriter is very efficient:

```
    byte[] ToBytes() {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(somelength);
        var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);
        bw.Write(SomeShort);
        bw.Write(SomeOtherShort);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Lots of MemoryStream methods are a no-op.  Flush() and Dispose() are not necessary.  You can call them if you prefer, the JIT optimizer will just remove the call.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to initialize `tmp` to a new array. `BitConverter.GetBytes` creates a new array and returns it for you. There's not much you can do about `GetBytes` but you can use methods like [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) to simplify the copy operation.

If you're not doing this in a performance-critical piece of code, you can go a bit LINQy and do things like:

```
IEnumerable<byte> bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(first);
bytes = bytes.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(second));
bytes = bytes.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(third));
// ... so on; you can chain the calls too
return bytes.ToArray();
```

Comment: Well, is performance intense.. as in called in a very tight loop multiple times..

Comment: @Earlz: All the more reason not to use the same broken interface that BitConverter has, because now the loop calling your GetBytes is faced with the exact same problem.

Comment: Well, we ended up just doing it the hardware and using BlockCopy to help us.. Linq is just too slow in this case..

Comment: @Mehrdad, sorry I gave away the accepted answer, but I later converted from this code to his code and it is much much cleaner. And if it takes few extra microseconds, then it's not *that* performance critical..

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size beforehand (have a set of value types) you could use a struct and assign your values in the struct. Then use `unsafe` code to copy the raw bytes. I would still advise against it unless it's really necessary for speed purposes. And you might think it's painful :)

```
private struct MyStruct
{
    public short A;
    public short B;

    public MyStruct(short a, short b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

private unsafe byte[] UnsafeStruct(MyStruct myStruct)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4]; // where 4 is the size of the struct
    fixed (byte* ptr = buffer)
    {
        *((MyStruct*)ptr) = myStruct;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bit-shift...

```
buffer[0]=(byte)SomeShort;
buffer[1]=(byte)(SomeShort >> 8);
buffer[2]=(byte)SomeOtherShort;
buffer[3]=(byte)(SomeOtherShort >> 8);
```

This also means you are in complete control of the endian-ness (in this case, little-endian)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code a little shorter by using Array.Copy, but no there isn't any GetBytes overload or equivalent in BitConverter that puts the bytes directly into your buffer.

Maybe [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write.aspx) on a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) is what you want?

Note that by adopting the API conventions of BitConverter which you don't like, you're causing the same problem for users of your class.  Instead, write a method which accepts a BinaryWriter and serializes your class into it, this extends nicely when your class is embedded in some other object.

Comment: Not an answer.. should've been a comment.. plus you have the rep to fix it.. (btw, I didn't downvote you)

Comment: True, I guess I shouldn't post an answer while I'm still writing it.  I use ninja edits way too much and sometimes people see a half-answer.